Progress Bar is not updated in TCL script
I'm using a third party software which allows me to add simple/basic gui's in TCL. My script is very basic, it copies files from certain directories and then zips the folder.
Since some of the files are relatively large, the zipping process takes a while. Therefore I would like to provide user some visual cues as to what is happening when script is executing.
Now I have done all of the above, added the progress bar but can't seem to update it i.e. no green bar progressing from 0% to 100%
Below are some snippets of the progress bar code.
set v 0
ttk::progressbar $tw.pbt.p1 -orient horizontal -length 200  -mode determinate -maximum 100 -variable v 
gridrc 1 1 $tw.pbt.p1  -sticky we -padx 5 -pady 10 -columnspan 3
grid columnconfigure $tw.pbt 2 -weight 1

Please note, the above code is written within the frame of the thrid party software hence "gridrc" ( I think it is specific to their environment).
for {set v 0} {$v < 1000} {incr v 10} { 

after 100; update }

The For loop is within a procedure as it is executed when the User presses a button to copy files. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get -variable v update the progress bar.
I wonder if someone can identity my mistake or point me to an example.
ps: looked at the Active State Active TCL example on progress bar, could understand how the "start button" was updating the progress bar.
Thanks you in advance.

Did you make v global in the procedure? Otherwise the for loop will just update a local variable called v, which is different from the (global) variable v attached to the progress bar.

Maybe "update idletasks" will help? From the man page: "The update idletasks command is useful in scripts where changes have been made to the application's state and you want those changes to appear on the display immediately,..."  Also, the progress bar value goes to 100, but you're counting to 1000?

Hi Mike, "update idletasks" helped and now code works. Thanks a lot. btw I was messing with the code so must have forgotten to change.

The two possible causes are:

Not running the event loop (but you are calling update so this shouldn't apply), and
Not updating the correct variable. This seems more likely.

Tk widgets resolve their state variables in the global namespace (of a particular Tcl interpreter). Always have done. If your for loop is running in a procedure or a different interpreter, the v variable will be different, and that widget will not see the change.
If you are in a procedure, add global v to its body before you start looking.
If you are in a different interpreter, the easiest option is to run the code in the correct interpreter! You can do complicated things with traces to synch stuff between interpreters... but it really isn't something I'd recommend when just running the code in the right place is so much easier in most circumstances. (If you can't connect to the interpreter running the GUI to do this at all, you're probably stuck. Interpreter boundaries are designed to be security boundaries.)
